# How to mark or delete or cross html input field text

Tags: html, css

When the user types the input value I want to show the input field text like the below style:

<del>this style I want to apply in input text</del>

I didn't get any idea how to do this.

Comment: Funny enough, you can use your browser's DevTools to select the element your example text is in and see the `text-decoration: line-through` CSS that causes that display

Answer (score 3):

With [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration), for example:

```css
input {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

The terminology you want for searching is probably "strike through", as terms like "cross" and "delete" are unlikely to find what you're looking for in this case.  (Though you did just introduce me to the `<del>` HTML element.  Which I've never needed and probably never will, but it's good to know what it is in case I encounter it.)